# How to Insert into oracle DB, with a value selected from same table

Tags: oracle

To Oracle database table, i want to insert a row.
Ex: INSERT INTO abc (a, b, c) VALUES (x, y,z).

Here the x values should be the max(a) + 1.

How to do the same.
If Null is returned by max(a), then i need to make x as 1.

Comment: If you have the possibility to use a [`SEQUENCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm) (or autokey in Oracle 12) for generating values for `a`, the solution is much more simpler and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
        insert into tablename
        select nvl(max(column1)+1,1),column2 from table2
        where  <Condition here> group by <condition>;
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Insert into..select statement.
create table abc (x number, y number, z number);
    insert into abc select nvl(max(x),1), 2,3 from abc;